# Remember search query in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Is there any way to make Sublime Text 3 remember the previously entered search query in the "go to anything"?

I frequently use the "go to anything" to jump to line numbers. If Sublime Text could remember the last entered query I would not have to remember the line number and type it again.

I am already familiar with the bookmarks function and it is not really an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **use a plugin that saves the content** of the gotoAnything-panel when its modified, and then puts the content on the panel when it gets opened.

Basic plugin example:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class GotoAnythingSaver(sublime_plugin.EventListener): # Use EventListener
    # In my case gotoAnything view id is 2.

    def on_modified(self, view): # This is called when a view is modified (text changed)
        if (view.id() == 2): # Save content
            self.content = self.get_view_content(view)

    def on_activated_async(self, view): # This is called when a view is activated
        if view.id() == 2 and hasattr(self, 'content'): # Restore content if empty
            if not self.get_view_content(view):
                view.run_command('insert', {"characters":self.content})

    def get_view_content(self, view):
        return view.substr(sublime.Region(0, view.size()))
```

To save the plugin use menu *Tools>new Plugin* and then save it in the given folder (folder name should be *User*), use fileName *GotoAnythingSaver.py*.

---

Example result used to go to the same line again:

[image: Sublime goto anything saver, a plugin that restores goto-anythin content]

---

**Edit:** tested on Sublime Text 3 build 3103 on Linux Mint and Windows 10. *OP* says this plugin leave the gotoanything dysfunctional, this doesn't happened to me, but be careful.

I would appreciate if someone could test it or help me, because I am not sure if the identifier of the view associated with goto-anything panel is always 2.

Comment: On a second note, adding this plugin did nothing but leave the gotoanything dysfunctional. I even deleted the plugin and now the "Go to anything" does not work at all.

Comment: Wow. What version and SO are you using? Please use menu `View>Show console` and then try to open goto-anything and tell me the errors that console shows.

Comment: I must have done something wrong because I tested this today and it works perfectly! Sorry for the delay and thanks a lot for this solution!

Comment: I've tested it on ST3, and the Go to Anything id is always different even in different windows and layout groups.